# Unable to deploy code onto AWS EC2 instance from AWS CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-codebuild

I am trying to implement CI/CD using AWS CodeBuild, and trying to deploy an application onto an AWS EC2 instance, but the code deployment is failing and showing the error below:

> The IAM role arn:aws:iam::341502448925:role/CodeDeployServiceRole does not give you permission to perform operations in the following AWS service: AmazonEC2

I have even created service role in the `IAM` console but it's not working for me. Someone let me know how can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Except for creating an IAM role you should also install aws codedeploy agent on your ec2 instance:
[install aws-codedeploy agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install-linux.html)

Comment: I have set up codedeploy-agent  on server but its showing this error when deployment is failed `The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems.`

Comment: I guess you define some autosacling_group that let assume will deploy on 3 different  instances. 
thats mean that he trying to deploy (meaning codedeploy is working), but probably some scripts failed in 1 or more instances. 

take a look at the logs in your instances under:

/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-logs/codedeploy-agent-deployments.log

Comment: When I am trying to access logs there `/codedeployment-agent` directory is missing when I am running `cd /codedeploying-agent` its saying `-bash: cd: /codedeploy-agent: No such file or directory` after going into `/opt`.